# Laravel - Undefined offset: 1 - Adding new form inputs as an array when updating

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an error **Undefined offset: 1** it persists when I add new array of form inputs when updating. here is my web UI where I add a new form input

So when I click the **+** button then it will add new form inputs

but the problem is .. when I click save or submit.. the error persists 
here is the error.

I tried to put array but nothing still works. any suggestions to this or better an answer, please? here is my code.

Comment: Try putting dd($request->all()) at the beginning of controller to get all the request data and provide the result here. This will be useful for checking and debugging purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very silly mistakes though... change `for($x = 0; $x <= $countvideos; $x++)` to `for($x = 0; $x < $countvideos; $x++)`

Comment: hello sir, can you please explain why is it a mistake?